# Lambda Expression joining another table in my query for average

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to join a table (db.Students) within this query to get firstname and lastname included in the query by joining on the StudentID. How do I do this? I've come up with about 50 queries that don't work and one that only gives me half of what I want. This is what I have so far that is working.

```
            var gradeaverages = db.Grades
                .Where(r => r.StudentID == r.StudentID)
                .GroupBy(g => g.StudentID, r => r.Grades)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    StudentID = g.Key,
                    Rating = g.Average()
                });
        var data = gradeaverages.ToList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```

It does have a foreign key. Here is the constraint: 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Grades_Students] FOREIGN KEY ([StudentID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Students] ([StudentID])

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Grades] (
[GradeID]   INT          NOT NULL,
[StudentID] INT          NOT NULL,
[Date]      NCHAR (10)   NULL,
[Grades]    DECIMAL (18) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([GradeID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Grades_Students] FOREIGN KEY ([StudentID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Students] ([StudentID])


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students] (
[StudentID]  INT           NOT NULL,
[First Name] NVARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
[Last Name]  NVARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
[Phone]      NVARCHAR (24) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StudentID] ASC)
```

I'm looking for an out put of

StudentID    FirstName   LastName     AverageGrade (according to StudentID I assume)

Comment: Does your db have foreign key grades -> students? Are you using EF?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you be more specific on exactly how you want your output to be, compared to what it is at the moment?

Comment: What is your table structure like? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is not enough information about db structure, but I guess your query might look like this:

```
var data = db.Students.Include("Grades")
    .Select(x => new
    {
       StudentId = x.StudentId,
       Rate = x.Grades.Avg(y => y.Mark)
    })
    .ToList();
```

This `.Where(r => r.StudentID == r.StudentID)` is meaningless, because you compare some value with itself.

Or like this

```
var data = db.Grades
    .GroupBy(x => x.StudentId)
    .Select(x => new
    {
       StudentId = x.Key,
       Rate = x.Avg(y => y.Mark)
    })
    .ToList();
```